# Enforce MSAL login with specific user in .NET

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Is there a way to require user to login into Azure AD only with specific account in interactive mode, using MSAL?

I tried

`NativeClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).WithLoginHint(account.Username).ExecuteAsync()`

and

`NativeClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).WithAccount(account).ExecuteAsync()`

but both allow me to select user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use `WithPrompt(Prompt.NoPrompt)` to exclude all other accounts that you not want to choose.

Just try code below:

```
NativeClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.NoPrompt).WithLoginHint("<account>").ExecuteAsync()
```

**Result:**

**NOT** using `WithPrompt(Prompt.NoPrompt)`:
[image]

**Using** `WithPrompt(Prompt.NoPrompt)`:

[image]

Comment: Thank. But Sign in with another account is still there as a link..